# Ошибка Failed to resolve: firebase-database-15.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Пытаюсь подключить Firebase, просит сделать вот это -> 
В итоге выдает ошибку Failed to resolve: firebase-database-15.0.0. Помогите уже целый день убил((
Версия android studio 3.2.0

[image: Пытаюсь подключить Firebase, просит сделать вот это ->]

[image: В итоге выдает ошибку Failed to resolve: firebase-database-15.0.0. Помогите уже целый день убил((]

Comment: Скриншоты редко когда подходят для публикации вопроса. Попробуйте лучше текстом в вопросе, через правку оного, показать скрипты сборки (build.gradle файлы, 2 шт.).

Comment: В dependencies нижнея строчка "com.google........firabase-database:16.0.1:15.0.0" убери окончание чтоб осталось "com.google........firabase-database:16.0.1"

Comment: @Михаил когда убираю это окончание, ошибка конечно уходит, но "Add the Realtime Database to your app" не будет отмечена зеленым

Comment: Должно работать я думаю, главное что ты законнектился с Database, проверь

Comment: @Михаил спасибо большое , всё работает!